# jQuery UI Buttons Background Color/Image Shows Through Rounded Corners (Sometimes)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, rounded-corners

I have been using jQuery UI for a while now and recently have started seeing some artifacts around the corner edges of buttons that have rounded corners.

Here is a picture and a zoom in of what I am talking about. You can see the border of the button is yellow and the background of the button is purple. Sometimes (not all the time) the background color "bleeds" through the rounded corner border. Giving it a sort of blurry non-clean look. more contrasting colors are even worse.

[link to bad corner image](http://www.masterkeyhost.com/bad_corner_test.jpg)

I see this on any jQuery UI elements that have rounded corners: dialogs, tabs, accordians, etc...

No special/custom styles have been applied. This is just the default themeroller output.

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and UI 1.9.2.

Has anybody else noticed this and/or does anybody know of a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I knew I forgot something: Firefox 19 - looks bad, Chrome 24 - looks bad, Safari 5.1 - looks good (interesting), haven't checked IE yet...

Comment: To reassure you, I'm having a similar problem.  On dark back-grounds I can see artefacts where the button edge would be on a 'square' button.  I'm using Chrome 26.  If I find a solution, I'll come back here.